# Question about inverse with respect to convolution product.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{I}(X)$ be the collection of real valued functions  $f:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $f(x,y)=0$ when $x>y$. The convolution product $f*g$ for $f,g\in \mathcal{I}(X)$ is defined by $$ f*g(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \sum_{\lbrace z:x\le y\le z\rbrace}f(x,z)g(z,y) & x\le y \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
From page 14 of http://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Math232/Inclusion-Exclusion.pdf, I don't follow the last step.

[image]

If the latest summ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta, is equal to $\delta(x,y)$, wouldn't that imply the sum representing $g(x,y)$ is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It means, if $x<y$ then
$$\sum_{x\le z\le y} g(x,z)\,f(z,y)=0\,.$$
And, also $g(x,x)\,f(x,x)=1$.

For example, if $y$ covers $x\ $ ($y>x$ and there is no element in between), we have
$$g(x,y)=-\frac1{f(y,y)}\big(g(x,x)\,f(x,y)\big)=-\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x,x)\,f(y,y)}\,.$$
Then
$$g(x,x)\,f(x,y)\ +\ g(x,y)\,f(y,y)\ =\ \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x,x)}\ +\ \frac{-f(x,y)}{f(x,x)}\ =\ 0$$
indeed.